# Cursor inside cell datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

VB.NET DataGridView control:

I know this is probably super simple, but how can I put the blinking cursor inside a specific cell on form load?

I want the effect to be kind of like when you have a form with text boxes and when you set the tab order correctly, the first textbox will automatically have the focus and you can start typing right away.

On a related question: how can I make the enter key activate the form's accept button when you're inside a cell?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it is fairly easy to position the input cursor to a specific cell in a DataGridView.  Set the DataGridView's [`CurrentCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) property to the cell you want the cursor in and then call the DGV's [`BeginEdit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.beginedit.aspx) method.

It's also easy to programmatically click (which I believe is what you mean by 'activate') a form's `AcceptButton`.  Call the [`PerformClick`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.ibuttoncontrol.performclick.aspx) method on the form instance's `AcceptButton`:

```
Me.AcceptButton.PerformClick()
```

Getting the DGV to handle the Enter key is a little trickier even though it might not seem so on the surface.  The reason it is tricky is because when you have a DGV cell in edit mode, the DGV `KeyPress` and `PreviewKeyPress` events don't fire.  The solution is to create your own DataGridView by extending the standard DataGridView and then overriding the `ProcessCmdKey` function to fire an event that tells listeners the Enter key was pressed.

Here's what your extended DGV control might look like:

```
Public Class MyDataGridView
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView

    Public Event EnterKeyPressed()

    Protected Overrides Function ProcessCmdKey(ByRef msg As System.Windows.Forms.Message, ByVal keyData As System.Windows.Forms.Keys) As Boolean
        If keyData = Keys.Enter Then
            RaiseEvent EnterKeyPressed()
        End If

        Return MyBase.ProcessCmdKey(msg, keyData)
    End Function
End Class
```

So assuming you're using the extended DGV above here's how you can do what you need to do:

```
' This positions the input cursor in the third column in the third row.
MyDataGridView1.CurrentCell = MyDataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(2)
MyDataGridView1.BeginEdit(False)


' Be sure to wire up the EnterKeyPress event on your shiny new MyDataGridView.
Private Sub MyDataGridView1_EnterKeyPressed() Handles MyDataGridView1.EnterKeyPressed
   Me.AcceptButton.PerformClick()
End Sub
```

Comment: @John Not sure why, it works for me.  Could the cause be any changes you've made to the DGV's properties?  Does it work if you use a new DGV (or a `MyDataGridView`) in a new form?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it will definitely work

```
dim strRowNumber as string

For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGrid.Rows

     strRowNumber = DataGrid.Rows.Count - 1
     DataGrid.CurrentCell = DataGrid.Rows(strRowNumber).Cells(1)'Cell(1) is a cell nowhich u want to edit or set focus
     DataGrid.BeginEdit(False)
Next
```